# adb on ubuntu won't connect to my android phone via usb or wifi

Tags: android, ubuntu, usb, adb, wifi

I am unable to connect to android phone using adb on my ubuntu computer.

I have enabled Developer Options on the Android phones and enabled USB debugging
After connecting the phone with the USB cable, i selected transferring files (for the usb connection). The device also shows up in my favourites bar.

When I run `adb devices` the phone doesn't show up.

So, I've also tried wifi:
I enabled Wireless debugging and made note of the ip and port that are displayed
I then run `adb connect *ip:port*`. This returns 'connected to *ip:port*', but when i run `adb devices` it shows as offline. Furthermore, when I try `adb shell` it doesn't work because my device is offline (or so it says).
When I telnet to this ip and port, it immediately connects, so connectivity is not an issue.

I've tried this with two android phones (samsung and pixel), running Android 13 and 12.
I've also tried all the different usb ports that my computer has.

Android studio is not installed and I don't want to install it either.

Comment: Try launch adb on another port: adb -P 5038 start-server